# error:expected intializer before 'void'(How to fix it?)

Tags: c++

I got this problem when I tried to code for competitive programming courses, but I got this problem about void:

Code 1:
On the first code, it could be executed properly. the void didn't need to be initialized and everything works really well.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdio>

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define ll long long

#define ar array

using namespace std;

int n; int b;int a[100000];

void solve(){

    cin >> n >> b;

    for(int i =0;i <n;++i){

        cin >> a[i];

    }

    sort(a,a+n);

    int ans=0;

    for(int i=0;i < n;++i){

        if(b>=a[i]){

            b-=a[i];

            ++ans;
        } 
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}

int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int t;int e=1;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        cout << "Case #" << e <<":";
        solve();
    }
}
```

```
Output:
Success
```

but on another code, the void need to be initialized ,and when I call it in main,it isn't declared on the scope.is there something wrong with the code?or i need to redownload the gcc?
code 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
#define ar array
int a; int b;int c[10000]
void solution(){
    cin >> a >> b;
    string f;
    cin >> f;
    while(a--){
        string l;int x; int y; int z;
        cin >> l >> x >> y >> z;
        cout << l << x << y << z endl;
    }
}
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
    solution();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
seleksi_olimpiade.cpp:7:1: error: expected initializer before 'void'
    7 | void solution(){
      | ^~~~
seleksi_olimpiade.cpp: In function 'int main()':
seleksi_olimpiade.cpp:23:5: error: 'solution' was not declared in this scope
   23 |     solution();
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon (`;`) after `int c[10000]`.

Comment: Yep, and that's why a [mcve] is a must for such questions. Please, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `cout << l << x << y << z endl;`  this is wrong ,it should be `cout << l << x << y << z<< endl;`

Comment: Use namespace at the top , `using namespace std;`  at the beginning

Comment: @Mureinik Hey, I'm relatively new to SO. When to point out code mistakes in a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @a.Li If it's just a typo and it's unlikely anyone else will benefit from this answer in the future, use a comment. Otherwise, use an answer.

Comment: @Mureinik, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Escape the [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon in line `int a; int b;int c[10000]`

Comment: Ah.., thanks man,i really forgot about it.Thank you.

Comment: Good tip, when you get an error on a particular line, always look at the previous line to see if there's anything wrong with it. Don't take compiler error messages too literally.

Comment: @john Appreciate it man